# Proper way to release CGMutablePathRef Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGMutablePathRef path;
```

I have tried

```
self.path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(self.path, nil, elipseRect);
CGPathAddRect(self.path, nil, view.bounds);

CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.path = self.path;
layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
view.layer.mask = layer;
[self setupButton];

CGPathCloseSubpath(self.path);

    . . .

    . . .

CGPathRelease(self.path);
```

Releasing the path shows following error when Analyzing

Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code is all in a simple sequence like you showed, why are you using a property (`self.path`) for the path, rather than just a local variable? Also, it's a really bad idea to make any property of a mutable type. The caller can obtain the mutable reference and then mutate it without any further invocations of your class's methods, which makes your class blind to changes to its own state.

If you really need a property, you should probably do what Apple does. Although the property is declared (or defaults to) `assign`, document that it's actually strong. Implement the setter yourself to provide strong semantics (retain the new value, release the old). Also, don't forget to override `-dealloc` and release the instance variable there, too.

See, for example, the `path` property of `MKOverlayPathRenderer`. It's of type `CGPathRef`, which means it defaults to `assign` and can't be declared `strong` or `retain`, but it is documented as actually being strong.

If you do this, you have to be careful with the assignment. You either need to use a local and release it after assigning to the property, or you need to use `CFAutorelease()` (little known, but does what you would expect). So, either:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
self.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Or:

```
self.path = (CGMutablePathRef)CFAutorelease(CGPathCreateMutable());
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to help me and for your explanation. This works like charm.  This is just a sample code to explain my issue. Thanks Again.